# Test if a class is inherited from another

Tags: python, unit-testing

This question is more Python related than Django related. I want to test write a test for this function that I am using to get a Django form dynamically with the fields I set.

```
def quiz_form_factory(question):
    properties = {
        'question': forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput, initial=question.id),
        'answers': forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=question.answers_set)
    }
    return type('QuizForm', (forms.Form,), properties)
```

I want to test if, the QuizForm class returned is inherited from forms.Form.

Something like:

```
self.assertTrue(QuizForm isinheritedfrom forms.Form)  # I know this does not exist
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Use [issubclass(myclass, parentclass)](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#issubclass).

In your case:

```
self.assertTrue( issubclass(QuizForm, forms.Form) )
```

Comment: @bcdan really? It works for direct, indirect or virtual inheritance.

Comment: @Bo. I tested it with subclasses. if `class A`, `class B(A)`, and `class C(B)`, `C.issubclass(A)` returns `False`. I might have gotten terminology incorrect, but I'm just saying this technicality doesn't work for completeness of the answer.

Comment: Old thread, but for completeness:  bcdan is not correct.  At least in Python 3.x, the example he gives above returns True, as indicated by the docs.

Comment: @bcdan the way to do it is `issubclass(C, A)`. I did this on Python 2.7, and it worked with both new and old style classes.

Comment: In version 3.7, i tested issubclass(C, A). It returned True.

Answer (score 15):

Use the built-in [`issubclass`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#issubclass) function. e.g.

```
issubclass(QuizForm, forms.Form)
```

It returns a `bool` so you can use it directly in `self.assertTrue()`