# Python - Dynamic class import

Tags: python, python-import

I have the following folder structure:

```
- MyProject
    - App1
        - some_module1.py
        - some_module2.py
    - App2
        - some_other_module1.py
        - some_other_module2.py
```

Inside each of the modules (some_module1.py for example) there is a class that extends from a base class, in my case, Producer.

What I am trying to do is dynamically load in this class. To do that, I have a list of "installed apps" that looks like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'App1',
    'App2',
)
```

I am trying to write a function that will check each "app" package for a particular producer class and ensure it extends from the producer base class. Something like this:

```
module_class = 'some_module1.SomeClass'

# Loop through each package in the INSTALLED_APPS tuple:
for app in INSTALL_APPS:
    try:
        #is the module_class found in this app?
        #App1.some_module1.SomeClass - Yes
        #App2.some_module1.SomeClass - No

        # is the class we found a subclass of Producer?
    exception ImportError:
        pass
```

I've tried experimenting with imp and importlib, but it doesn't seem to handle this kind of import. Is there anyway for me to be able to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry - it is not possible to figure out what you want - your pseudocode is unclear. Python does take care of abse classes coming from the right places, howeer. So that Any App1.Class_ will see "Producer" as it is defined inside the App1 module.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to be as clear as possible. I have edited to the post and hope it makes more sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to have a look at:

- `__import__()` to import modules knowing their name as string;
- `dir()` to get the names of all the objects of a module (attributes, functions, etc);
- `inspect.isclass(getattr(<module ref>, <object name>))` to identify classes among the objects of a module;
- `issubclass()` to identify sub-classes from a given class, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628084/test-if-a-class-is-inherited-from-another).

With these tools, you can identify all classes in a given module, that are inheriting a given class.

I'm using this mechanism to dynamically instantiate classes from given module, so that their updates are automatically taken into account at an upper level.