# How to get a list of all classes that an object is an instance of?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, inheritance

Let's say I have the following code:

```
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

class C(B):
    pass

obj = C()
```

Then, `obj` is an instance of all three classes `A`, `B`, and `C`. This can be verified by calling `isinstance(obj, cls)`.

Is there a way to do the inverse, that is to have a function which returns a list of all classes that an object is an instance of?

So, `isinstanceof(obj)` would return `[A, B, C]`.

Comment: Technically speaking, `obj` is an instance of class C who inherits from B (who in turn inherits from A). Having said that there is a method to check if a class is a subclass (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628084/test-if-a-class-is-inherited-from-another) question) 
As far as I know there is no built in method to get the parent, but you can create a method in each subclass to get the parent (see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091957/get-parent-class-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the Method Resolution Order, which you can get via the class.

```
obj.__class__.__mro__
```

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get is to traverse the method resolution order (MRO) on the type of `obj` (which is `C`):

```
type(obj).__mro__
```

would give you:

```
(__main__.C, __main__.B, __main__.A, object)
```

You can also call the `mro` method instead of using the dunder `__mro__` attribute on the type:

```
type(obj).mro()
```